# My website is not responsive in mobile devices

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgid9.png)I am using this template https://templated.co/fetchingly for my website. But its not responsive. I am not a ui developer but i have seen w3 schools and other tutorials and see that all the required tags are indeed included. But still its not responsive. Can any one please help me on this to make my website responsive?

It looks good in normal desktop but in mobiles and ipad i can see the div is not responsive. The div is overlapped with the color and cant see the text.

Comment: Instead of negative comments can anyone please respond whats wrong here..so that i can try to correct it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve you haven't asked a good question. Downvotes mean "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"

Comment: @Isaac I have included every information in it. And i am learning UI just started infact. Can anyone please help me here

Comment: you have included no information... you tagged html5 and css3, yet you haven't posted any related html or css? Dare I suggest it, but perhaps even a screenshot of the issue? An MCVE would be preferred

Comment: @Isaac included the screen shots. And the code can be directly downloaded from the link. Please let me know if anything else needs to be added.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/Requ%C3%AAtes_m%C3%A9dia/Utiliser_les_Media_queries).

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  .yourDiv { 
    yourCss;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. But what should be the css in it? i dont have any css for that div

Answer (score 0):

You could specify media queries to change the display based on various resolutions like the below code, or even you could use Bootstrap it will make it easier.

```css
    /* Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px) */

    @media only screen  (max-width: 575.98px) {
        .some-selector {
            /* Property: value;*/
        }
    }

    /* Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up) */

    @media only screen (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) {
        .some-selector {
            /* Property: value;*/
        }
    }

    /* Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up) */

    @media only screen (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px) {
        .some-selector {
            /* Property: value;*/
        }
    }

    /* Large devices (desktops, 992px and up) */

    @media only screen (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199.98px) {
        .some-selector {
            /* Property: value;*/
        }
    }

    /* Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */

    @media only screen (min-width: 1200px) {
        .some-selector {
            /* Property: value;*/
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you not try using the Bootstrap framework? If you don't try before learn how to creating responsive web design with bootstrap.

Or you need to learn about using HTML and CSS to resize, hide, shrink, enlarge, or move the content to make it look good on any screen.

A few resources to improve yourself;

[**HTML Responsive Web Design**](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)

[**Responsive Web Design With Css**](https://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/)

[**Responsive Web Design With Bootstrap**](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp)